# Is there any difference between OS version beside DE and support time?

Tags: desktop-environments, lts

I'm sorry if this has been questioned many times, but I'm still not sure I understand fully.

what's the different between LTS and normal release? other than support time, of course. I mean, is there any specific OS feature?
IIRC, LTS on point-releases get updated kernel and DE version matching to normal release, right? And I don't really see many new non-DE feature.

Currently I'm using Unity in Mint 14, but doesn't feel much different from when I was using Ubuntu 12.04 (which means most of 12.04 feature is Unity's feature, right?)
I want to switch to Ubuntu again since people said 12.04.2 is pretty good. But I wonder if I should just wait for 13.04. If there's really no specific OS feature, and if 12.04.2 get the same Unity version as 13.04, then I'll pick 12.04.2 for longer support time.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This site works best when there's one question per post.

Comment: oh, sorry, didn't know that. Should I delete one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All a distro is is preinstalled software, and repositories. In an LTS this software, and the software in the repos is more stable. A desktop environment is just piece of software. In Ubuntu, Unity is installed by default, in mint, cinnamon or mate. However just because unity is the only one installed by default in ubuntu doesn't mean you can't use cinnamon or mate on it. IMHO there is a lot of oh I don't like Unity time to completely reinstall my OS around, when actually all they had to do was open the software centre and install another DE.

Comment: Here here! Just a load of drainers whinging and whining! Ubuntu bashing is the new microsoft bashing

Comment: so, beside this _default_ thing and the software choice of repo, there's really no OS version specific feature?

Comment: Exactly! However if you choose a completely different distro to ubuntu; eg: red hat, you would find it hard to set it up to install software from the ubuntu repos.